# Python: Opening specific file with latest timestamp in name

Tags: python, string

I have set of JSON files in my directory that look like this:

```
P2096_20240221114151310.json
QA558_20240223154745500.json
QA558_20240223165244591.json
```

what I want to do is pass the string to the left of the underscore as an argument, and then open the json file with the latest timestamp in the name.

This is what I have so far:

```
import glob

def get_file(name):

    files = glob.glob('./*.json')
    correct_files = []
    for file in files:
        file = file.strip('.\\')
        
        if file.startswith(name):
            correct_files.append(file)

    print(correct_files)

get_file('QA558')
```

And that gets me to here:

```
['QA558_20240223154745500.json', 'QA558_20240223165244591.json']
```

That is where I am stuck.  I know after I find the max timestamp, I will add the `with` statement to load the file as data, I just don't know how to get to that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce your exact behaviour so I used an array instead but you should get a hint for your code since this worked out pretty well for me, with a .json file in the same folder.

```py
def get_file(name):

    files = ['P2096_20240221114151310.json','QA558_20240223154745500.json','QA558_20240223165244593.json', 'QA558_20240223165244591.json']
    correct_files = ""
    for file in files:
        file = file.strip('.\\')

        # Check for correct name and if correct file is empty or if the current file is newer than the correct file
        if file.startswith(name) and (not correct_files or file > correct_files):
            correct_files = file

    # Open the file with read
    with open(correct_files, 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())

    print(correct_files)

get_file('QA558')
```

As an output, I receive my sample json and the highest .json file found.

```bash
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "age": 30,
  "city": "New York"
}

QA558_20240223165244593.json
```

Comment: This works great, but I am confused as to how it is working.  I guess I didnt think you could iterate over strings that have characters/integers and end in '.json' and get the max one.  Either way though thank you!

Comment: I think the missing keyword you need to know is lexicographical comparison or also known as lexicographical order. This means it compares both strings character by character based on their Unicode code point values.
Therefore, comparing strings makes only sense when they have a consistent structure.

Answer (score 2):

Start by embedding the name in the pattern itself. Then use `max` to get the largest value according to an appropriate key function.

```
import glob

def get_file(name):

    files = glob.glob(f'./{name}_*.json'))
    if files:
        return max(files,
                   key=lambda x: x.split('_')[0].remove_suffix('.json')
                  )
    else:
        return None
        # or raise an exception, or something
```

If you are happy with returning `None`, you can simply return `max(files, default=None, key=...)` without checking if `files` is empty or not. If you are going to raise an exception, you can either let the `ValueError` raised by `max([], key=...)` bubble up, or catch it and raise a different exception of your own.

Comment: This is slick, thank you.  I dont know much about heaps so probably a good thing to learn

Comment: Ironically, `heapq.nlargest(1, ...)` doesn't even use a heap. It just uses `max`. Hm, I probably should have just used that in the first place...

Comment: Actually, `nlargest` returns a list anyway, so I might as well use `max` instead of returning the first element of that list.

Answer (score 1):

Split the date part, convert to datetime or not, sort.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

filelist = [
    "QA558_20240223154745500.json",
    "QA558_19990223165244591.json",
    "QA558_20240223165244591.json",
    "QA558_19940223165244591.json",
]

# Datetime not really needed I guess
# datelist = [datetime.strptime(os.path.splitext(x)[0].split("_")[-1], "%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f") for x in filelist]

datelist = [os.path.splitext(x)[0].split("_")[-1] for x in filelist]
sorted_datelist = sorted(datelist)
```

Output:

```
['19940223165244591',
 '19990223165244591',
 '20240223154745500',
 '20240223165244591']
```